# Проверка телефонных номеров

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

С помощью регулярного выражения нужно вернуть `true`, если номер подходит, иначе `false`.
Написал такой код

```js
//Logic for testing
function isTrue(str)
{
  if(telephoneCheck(str))
  {
    return '<span style="color:#00ff00">OK - telephoneCheck("'+str+'") return true</span><br>';
  }
  else
  {
    return '<span style="color:#ff0000">ERROR - telephoneCheck("'+str+'") return false (MUST BE true)</span><br>';
  }
}
function isFalse(str)
{
  if(telephoneCheck(str))
  {
    return '<span style="color:#ff0000">ERROR - telephoneCheck("'+str+'") return true (MUST BE false)</span><br>';
  }
  else
  {
    return '<span style="color:#00ff00">OK - telephoneCheck("'+str+'") return false</span><br>';
  }
}
function TEST()
{
  var retCode='';
  retCode+=isTrue("555-555-5555");
  retCode+=isTrue("1 555-555-5555");
  retCode+=isTrue("1 (555) 555-5555");
  retCode+=isTrue("5555555555");
  retCode+=isTrue("555-555-5555");
  retCode+=isTrue("(555)555-5555");
  retCode+=isTrue("1(555)555-5555");
  retCode+=isTrue("1 555 555 5555");
  retCode+=isTrue("1 456 789 4444");

  retCode+=isFalse("123**&!!asdf#");
  retCode+=isFalse("55555555");
  retCode+=isFalse("(6505552368)");
  retCode+=isFalse("2 (757) 622-7382");
  retCode+=isFalse("0 (757) 622-7382");
  retCode+=isFalse("-1 (757) 622-7382");
  retCode+=isFalse("2 757 622-7382");
  retCode+=isFalse("10 (757) 622-7382");
  retCode+=isFalse("27576227382");
  retCode+=isFalse("(275)76227382");
  retCode+=isFalse("2(757)6227382");
  retCode+=isFalse("2(757)622-7382");
  retCode+=isFalse("555)-555-5555");
  retCode+=isFalse("(555-555-5555");
  retCode+=isFalse("(555)5(55?)-5555");
  retCode+=isFalse("555-555");
  retCode+=isFalse("5555555");
  retCode+=isFalse("1 555)555-5555");
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = retCode;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function telephoneCheck(str) {//===!!!FixIt!!!===
        var regex = /1?\s?[\s\(]?[0-9]{3}[\)\s\-]?\s?[0-9]{3}[\s\-]*[0-9]{4}[^0-9]/g;
        if (regex.test(str)) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
    </script>
    <input type=button value="TEST" onclick="TEST()"/>
    <div id='content'>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[То-же но на Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cb0YqAXQ8EcRGLjx9lsy?p=preview)

Не уверен, что регулярка подходящая и выглядит запутано и не уверен, что нужно использовать `test`, может надо `search` или `match`.
В ответе желательно объяснить вашу регулярку.

Функция для исправлений помечена комментарием FixIt.

Список номеров для регулярки, использованный в тесте

Хорошие
"555-555-5555"
"1 555-555-5555"
"1 (555) 555-5555"
"5555555555"
"555-555-5555"
"(555)555-5555"
"1(555)555-5555"
"1 555 555 5555"
"1 456 789 4444"

Плохие
"123**&!!asdf#"
"55555555"
"(6505552368)"
"2 (757) 622-7382"
"0 (757) 622-7382"
"-1 (757) 622-7382"
"2 757 622-7382"
"10 (757) 622-7382"
"27576227382"
"(275)76227382"
"2(757)6227382"
"2(757)622-7382"
"555)-555-5555"
"(555-555-5555"
"(555)5(55?)-5555"
"555-555"
"5555555"
"1 555)555-5555"

Comment: Ну очешуеть :) Забыли ценник поставить. Или хотя бы примеры корректных номеров.

Comment: `RegExp#test()` - это то, что нужно, только `g` надо убрать. Ну, и поправить регулярку.

Comment: Примеры в демо, справа вверху на глаз нажать. После изменений кода нажать на зеленую кнопку со стрелками внутри, пример обновляться и проверит прохождение тестов.

Comment: Нужно из тестов выискивать то, на что нужно проверять?

Comment: Там большой список, я специально тесты написал, чтоб проверять удобней было. функция(номер) return true/false (это что должна вернуть). Если красным цветом текст, то не проходит, если черный текст и слева галочка то проходит. Думаете лучше в вопрос список телефонов вставить?

Comment: *В ответе желательно объяснить вашу регулярку.* - В вопросе желательно объяснить критерии проверки, а также список "хороших" и отдельно "плохих" строк. Вот тогда дело сдвинется с мёртвой точки.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "хороший" должен вернуть true, "плохой" false, т.е. где написано return true этот номер должен подходить под регулярку. Номера написаны в тесте telephoneCheck(номер).

Comment: Ваш вариант с тестами может быть удобен Вам, на данному ресурсе так не принято. Добавьте в вопрос необходимую информацию(пример номеров которые валидны/невалидны)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var regex = /^(1[ ]?)?(((\([0-9]{3}\)[ ]?)|([0-9]{3}[- ]?)))[0-9]{3}[- ]?[0-9]{4}$/;
```

А работает это так:

```
^ начало строки
(
    1[ ]? 1 с пробелом или без
)? есть или нет конструкции выше
(
    (
        (
        \([0-9]{3}\) з цифры в скобках
        [ ]? с пробелом или без
        )
    | или
        (
        [0-9]{3} з цифры без скобок
        [- ]? с дефисом, пробелом или без них
        )
    )
)
[0-9]{3} з цифры
[- ]? с дефисом, пробелом или без них
[0-9]{4} 4 цифры
$ конец строки
```

Comment: Код может не достаточно лаконичен и не самый "крутой". Но он работает.

Comment: Также хочу уточнить: 
при проверке 1 555-5555555 - true
при проверке 1 (555)-555-5555 - false
Этих примеров нет в вашем условии.